# Изменение модели в Mongoose в зависимости от условий

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В node я совсем новичок и хотелось бы понять, на сколько мое решение валидно и как еще можно сделать.
Есть файл user.js:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

userSchema.static('addField', function () {
    userSchema.add({company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }})
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Его я подключаю и при пост запросе, исходя из данных реквеста, а именно типа юзера хочу добавлять либо не добавлять поле "company" в модель.
Файл app.js:

```
const User = require("./models/user")

app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  let user
  if(req.body.role !== 'admin') {
    User.addField()
    user = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      age: req.body.age,
      role: req.body.role,
      company: req.body.company
    })
  } else {
    user = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      age: req.body.age,
      role: req.body.role
    })
  }
  user.save((err, user) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else res.send(user)
  })
})
```

Comment: Почему не менять модель, а сделать company не обязательным? Менять динамически модель - плохая идея: в другом месте захотите поменять фамилию, а какую модель в нем подключать? Излишнее усложнение логики.

Comment: @Friendly33 и даже в этом случае модель не должна что-то знать про "бизнес-логику". Валидация должна выполняться на более высоких уровнях. Но если совсем лениво валидировать данные в контроллере или логика роли "админа" никогда не будет меняться то можно использовать [кастомные валидаторы](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), благо их чуть больше чем достаточно. Например, `required: function() { return this.role !== 'admin'; }`. А ещё можно сделать company обязательным и админам писать `dummy`. В общем, что угодно, но не заниматься модификацией модели налету.